# Populate data into material-ui dropdown React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need some help, I want to populate data into a Dropdown, I'm using material-ui but I don't know how to do it, I really new to react, I know that I can use props and then pass those to the dropdown but It's not that clear for me.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';



export default class CreateLinksave extends React.Component {

 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {value: 1
   };
   this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
 }
 handleChange(event, index, value) {this.setState({value});}

render() {
 return (
    <div className="container">
     <div>
       <RaisedButton label="Copy an existing Global Multisave"/>
     </div>
      <div>
      <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <MenuItem value={1} primaryText="Never" />
        <MenuItem value={2} primaryText="Every Night" />
        <MenuItem value={3} primaryText="Weeknights" />
      </DropDownMenu>
      </div>
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

as you can see, I have some options in my dropdown "hardcoded" but I want to make it dynamic, so if more options are added to props then this populate them automatically.

Can someone please help me with this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can send those props as an array:

```
items = [
  { value: 1, primaryText: 'Never' },
  { value: 2, primaryText: 'Every Night' },
  { value: 3, primaryText: 'Weeknights' },
]
```

Simply map through them and you'll get the same result:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DropDownMenu value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <MenuItem key={item.value} {...item} />
        )}
      </DropDownMenu>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, just one more question, and don't know if its related to ES6 or something but Im getting an "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" on the array, the issue is on the "=" sign of the Items array.

Comment: Check whether you es6 configuration (mainly babel) supports arrow functions. If not, you can replace `=>` to `function(item) { return <MenuItem ... /> }` and that also works.

Comment: Looks like the syntax is a bit off, the start should be curly:  { this.props.item... NEVER MIND, i was able to edit post